# php cli строковые функции и кириллица

Tags: php, кириллица, консоль

Запускаю php скрипт, в котором вызываются методы ядра CMS работающие со строками. Через запуск скрипта из браузера, все работает. Но при попытке запустить через cli выводит неправильный результат.

Проанализировал код, понял, что проблема из-за работы функций substr и т.д. неправильно работают с кириллицей.

Если заменить функцию substr на mb_substr все работает.

Вопрос:
как можно без внесения изменений в ядро CMS (не заменяя напрямую substr  на mb_substr) заставить работать эти функции правильно?

Можно ли как-то задавать каике-то параметры работы php и т.д.?